# How do I temporary delete files with the command line?

Tags: linux

I've tried to alias `rm` with `rm='mv $1 /tmp/'` to no avail.

How can I temporary delete files with the command line?

I want to replace the `rm` command with the `mv` command to **not delete** my files and **create a trash** with the command line like I'm using the trash icon on my desktop.

Comment: "Temporarily delete" is an oxymoron. Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: I fixed my question. I want to move the files instead of remove. I want a trash in command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question is [answered here](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-9123.html). In summary;

- Adding an alias for `rm` is bad form, as other scripts (and/or users) on your system rely on the default behaviour
- When you switch to another machine you'll use `rm` with wild abandon
- Instead create an alias for your own command, such as `del`

To do this;

`alias del 'mv -i $1 /tmp'`

The `-i` flag warns you if a file of the same name already exists in trash, so you don't lose existing trashed files.

And you'll want that alias to be initiated whenever you open a shell, which depending on your system might be putting the command in `~/.bashrc`

Some people reported that `$1` doesn't work, and there's a suggested script in that thread I linked to which should help if that's the case.

Hope that helps